# How to identify hung slaves for a given jenkins master

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins master and a number of slaves statically (!) connected to it. That is to say, that each node doesn't have executors. I'm trying to identify hung slaves by monitoring how much time the slave handles a certain job in oreder to reboot the slave. I read carefully Groovy's documentation for Jenkins here:
http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/
but could not find any way to identify a busy slave. The only way I found that it can be done is relevant only if exectors are used (in a similar way to this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Find+builds+currently+running+that+has+been+executing+for+more+than+N+seconds).

Any idea how can I do it?

**edited:**
This is my solution using system Groovy script:

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.node_monitors.*
import hudson.slaves.*
import java.util.concurrent.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics    
jenkins = Hudson.instance    
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.*
import javax.activation.*    
import hudson.*;
import hudson.tasks.*;
import hudson.model.AbstractBuild
import hudson.Launcher
import hudson.model.BuildListener
import hudson.FilePath
import groovy.io.FileType
import jenkins.util.VirtualFile;



int MAX_ALLOWED_DURATION_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 30 // 30 minutes


for (computer in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.computers)
{
    for(e in computer.executors)
    {
        if(e.isBusy())
        {
            int durationInSeconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - e.executable.getStartTimeInMillis())/1000.0
            if(durationInSeconds > MAX_ALLOWED_DURATION_IN_SECONDS )
                {
                    print "restarting slave:"
                    println computer.getName()
                    println "\n\n\n"

                    def channel = computer.getChannel()
                    println RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(""""cmd /c shutdown -r".execute().text""",channel)
                    break
                }
        }
    }
}
println "Done"

return 0
```

Comment: Your question's title could be "how to identify hung slave for given jenkins master"..

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it myself, but try to apply `Computer.countBusy()` or `Computer.isIdle()` from [Computer](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html) class.

Comment: It might work, and I have already read about these methods earlier, but according to the documentation Computer class and the methods you mentioned are related to executors of a certain slave computer. However, in my case the only executor is the master and all slaves does not have executors because of the static connection. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: @MROB what does static connection mean?